# Using python to download table data without .csv file address provided

Tags: python, download, request

My purpose is to download the data from this website:
http://transoutage.spp.org/

When opening this website, in the bottom of web, there is a description used to illustrate how to auto-download the data. For example:
http://transoutage.spp.org/report.aspx?download=true&actualendgreaterthan=3/1/2018&includenulls=true

The code I wrote is this:

```
 import requests
 ul_begin = 'http://transoutage.spp.org/report.aspx?download=true'

 timeset = '3/1/2018' #define the time, m/d/yyyy 
 fn = ['&actualendgreaterthan='] + [timeset] + ['&includenulls=true']
 fn = ''.join(fn)
 ul = ul_begin+fn

 r = requests.get(ul, verify=False)
```

Since, if you input the web address, 
http://transoutage.spp.org/report.aspx?download=true&actualendgreaterthan=3/1/2018&includenulls=true,
into the Chrome, it will auto-download the data in .csv file. I do not know how to continue my code.

Please help me!!!!

Comment: Well, does this work? Does it give an error? Does it give a useful return value or status code in `r`?

Comment: The data you're looking for is contained within `r.content` - just `open` a file and `write` the content to it.  I just tried it and it produced a valid CSV.

Comment: You could use python's csv module to process the received csv data. Check https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the response you receive to a file:

```
r = requests.get(ul, verify=False)
if 200 >= r.status_code <= 300: 
    # If the request has succeeded
    file_path = '<path_where_file_has_to_be_downloaded>`
    f = open(file_path, 'w+')
    f.write(r.content)
    f.close()
```

This will work properly if the csv file is small in size. but for large files, you need to use `stream` param to download: http://masnun.com/2016/09/18/python-using-the-requests-module-to-download-large-files-efficiently.html

Comment: Thank you so much!! How can I set the download path? Since I did not find the download file, after I add the code into the original one and run it.

Comment: @bingqianhu In this example, since we dont explicitly specify the path, the file will be downloaded into the same folder from where you ran the code. You can also specify an exact path - `f = open('/home/ubuntu/Downloads/outfile.csv', 'w+')`. Edited the answer accordingly